# Source developed using Android 2.3.3 google Apis does not work for Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-emulator

I developer an Android app using Android 2.3.3 Google apis . The same source I tried to build again using Android 4.0.3 Google apis. But when I try to run the app the console is showing error as "Failed to install Shared Library" "Check LogCat  for more details". When checked in "Logcat" its showing error as  unable to find com.google.android.maps .Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

for eclipse you have to install GOOGle maps api seprately for each version might be your eclipse have Google Map api for 2.3 but not for 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You might forgot to add librery in your mainfest file.
add the following code within mainfest file( Inside Appication tag)

```
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Library management changed from r17. If you updated your ADT to this version or higher try this:

Right click project > Properties > Java Build > Order and Export

Move your libraries to the top